# WSL Ubuntu installation fails with the error: "Please restart WSL with the following command..."

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to run a Linux program on my laptop for the first time. My machine is running Windows 11. I've followed online guides for installing Ubuntu on WSL such as the ones here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/setup/environment

But when I install Ubuntu I get the error in the picture below:

[image: error message]

Here are the commands I've been running to try to resolve.

Confirming WSL is installed:

```
PS C:\Users\User> wsl --install

Windows Subsystem for Linux is already installed.
The following is a list of valid distributions that can be installed.
Install using 'wsl --install -d <Distro>'.

NAME               FRIENDLY NAME
Ubuntu             Ubuntu
Debian             Debian GNU/Linux
kali-linux         Kali Linux Rolling
SLES-12            SUSE Linux Enterprise Server v12
SLES-15            SUSE Linux Enterprise Server v15
Ubuntu-18.04       Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Ubuntu-20.04       Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
OracleLinux_8_5    Oracle Linux 8.5
OracleLinux_7_9    Oracle Linux 7.9

PS C:\Users\User> wsl -l -v
Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.
Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
https://aka.ms/wslstore
```

Install Ubuntu, launch, get the error message in the attached image.  Follow the command instructions in that error message:

```
PS C:\Users\User> wsl --shutdown
PS C:\Users\User> wsl --unregister Ubuntu
Unregistering...
There is no distribution with the supplied name.
```

Uninstall Ubuntu manually:

```
PS C:\Users\User> wsl --install -d Ubuntu
Installing: Ubuntu
Ubuntu has been installed.
Launching Ubuntu...
```

In a separate Ubuntu shell:

```
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370102
Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.
For information please visit https://aka.ms/enablevirtualization
Press any key to continue...
```

I've already enabled virtualization, confirmed with `systeminfo.exe`:

```
PS C:\Users\User> systeminfo.exe
...
Hyper-V Requirements:      VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
                           Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
                           Second Level Address Translation: Yes
                           Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes
```

Comment: Yep followed those instructions (obviously) but get the same error

Comment: Make sure your Windows is fully updated, WSL enabled, etc. This basically is a Windows question.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add those details as requested.

Comment: And, of course, **Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS** <- This seems to be the problem. Please check UEFI ("BIOS") settings.

Comment: I think I've enabled it, I run the systeminfe.exe command and can see "Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes" under the Hyper-V requirements. Is there another step after that's enabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you do seem to have virtualized enabled in the firmware, as you indicate:

```
Hyper-V Requirements:      VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
                           Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
```

But you don't appear to have the Virtual Machine Platform (VMP) enabled.  It should have been enabled during the initial `wsl --install`, but it looks like something went wrong.

On a Windows 11 system with the VMP (or Hyper-V) enabled, you'd see something slightly different in the `systeminfo.exe` results:

```
Hyper-V Requirements:      A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.
```

While this next suggestion is unlikely to *fix* the problem (but we can hope), it may at least give us a clue as to why the VMP isn't enabled.

From an Administrative PowerShell, run:

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart
```

<sub>From [Manual Installation - Step 3 - Enable Virtual Machine feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-3---enable-virtual-machine-feature)</sub>

Then restart the machine.

Watch closely during the reboot for any error messages that might appear.  If things look normal during the reboot, then from a non-admin PowerShell, try:

```
wsl --set-default-version 2
```

Followed by the `wsl --install -d Ubuntu` again.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Could you tell me how to undo this: ´´´´dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart´´´´ My Laptop is keeps go on after I click shutdown after I did this change

Comment: @mathandlogic Should be pretty much the opposite -- `dism.exe /online /disable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all`.  Also see [here](https://www.itechtics.com/enable-disable-windows-features/) for additional options.  If your system is having issues,  you may need to restart in Safe Mode to disable it.

Comment: @mathandlogic You should probably post a new question rather than trying to debug a separate problem in the comments :-).

Comment: Hehe I solved the problem by leaving out the all optiin

Answer (score 0):

For me this was caused by the location Ubuntu was attempting to unpack from(`%AppData%/Local/Packages/CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc`) had `compress contents to save disk space` enabled by default for some reason. I disabled that in the folders advanced options, and tried the installation again, and it succeeded.

I followed some of the directions found here: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/wslregisterdistribution-failed-with-error-0xc03a001a-2

[Screenshot of file settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwiox.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Please visit the following site and follow the instructions. I did and my problem was solved.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps

Comment: This is just a link not an answer. If there is important info at that link it needs to be in the answer written here.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This..**

## wsl and kali installation instructions step-by-step for windows server 2022

## for earlier distributions of windows you may need to install RSAT Tools to enable VirtualMachinePlatform and Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux

## for windows 10 https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=45520

## lets start

## Enable developer options from windows settings

## Download the Linux kernel update package to your desktop folder  # https://wslstorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/wslblob/wsl_update_x64.msi

## Download the kali linux wsl to your desktop folder # https://aka.ms/wsl-kali-linux-new

## Open PowerShell as administrator and execute

> > Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux

## Restart

## Open PowerShell as administrator and execute

> > dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart

> > dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart

## Restart

## Open PowerShell as administrator and execute

> > cd desktop

> > ./wsl_update_x64.msi

> > Add-AppxPackage .\KaliLinux_1.13.1.0.AppxBundle

> > wsl --set-default-version 2

> > kali # set your new unix username and password

> $exit

> > wsl --set-version kali-linux 2

> > start kali # welcome to Kali

> $sudo apt update

> $exit

> > explorer \\wsl.localhost

## congrats you got the wsl 2 installed on your machine

## if you are looking for the full functionality of kali linux you may execute the following commands

## that would consume around 25 GB of C drive and 1 to 3 hours to complete the download and installation

> > start kali

> $sudo apt install -y kali-win-kex

## select your language then press tab then ok

> $sudo apt install -y kali-linux-large

## macchanger select to automate the macchanger process every time you connect to new  network ethernet cable or reenable wifi

## kismet select run kismet as sudo so you don't need to type sudo when using kismet

## select Inted for sslh to reduce resource consuming

## Win-KeX provides a Kali Desktop Experience for Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL 2)

> > start kali

> $kex --esm --ip -s

## Enabling network connectivity in WSL 2

> > ipconfig

## Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL):

## IPv4 Address. : 172.22.64.1

## Subnet Mask . : 255.255.240.0

> $sudo ifconfig eth0 172.22.64.5 netmask 255.255.240.0

> $sudo route add default gw 172.22.64.1

> > netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=3390 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=3000 connectaddress=172.22.64.5

## also open port 3000 from windows firewall

## happy work!

Comment: It works for me and the installation done