# Installation of ubuntu in virtual box

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to install ubuntu 22.4 in virtual box after starting the ubuntu installation I am getting the this display and then black screen[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzKqJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

## Try this..

```
dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

some times virtual box got issues with 64x guest sessions you can reactivate it later if needed

```
dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All
```

why are you not using wsl check out that answer it may be better than vm if you need one Linux system built-in into your current windows installation!

https://askubuntu.com/a/1443559/1595574